# Llenar un Select por medio de un ciclo en Java Script LARAVEL

Tags: javascript, ajax, bucles, laravel-8, html-select

en esta ocasión traigo una duda o inconveniente que he tenido para renderizar una data en un select, esta data me llega como resultado de una petición ajax al controlador sin embargo al hacer un console.log me muestra un array de objetos y los atributos pero a su vez me muestra un error y nunca me carga la data en los options del select.

El error en consola es:

```
   (7) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}] 
   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
```

Pare este ejemplo la petición me retorna 7 registros, estos se muestran con un console.log sin problema (es decir, si llega la información)

El código es:

```js
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#id").change(function() {

            let id = $(this).val();
            let token = $("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr("content");
            console.log('Id: '+id);

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: `clients/${id}`,
                data: {
                    id: id,
                    _token: token,
                },
                /* si la respuesta es correcta, trajo un dato sin errores,  */
                success: function(response) {
                    if (response.length) {
                        $("#id_client").find('option').remove();
                        select = document.getElementById("id_client");
                        response.forEach((data) => {
                        option = document.createElement("option");
                        option.value = data.id;
                        option.text  = data.name;
                        select.appendChild(option);
                        console.log(data.name + ' - ' + data.id);
                    });
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Mi Select es de selección múltiple:

```html
<div class="form-group col-md-12">
  <label for="id_client"><b>Cliente</b></label>
  <select title="Seleccione clientes" class="selectpicker form-control" data-live-search="true" id="id_client" name="id_client[]" multiple="multiple">
  </select>
</div>
```

Agradezco de antemano sus aportes y experiencia.

Comment: Bienvenida al sitio, Patricia, por favor, reemplaza el código que tienes en formato de imagen en tu pregunta por código legible. Para algunos usuarios simplemente les es imposible determinar qué dice en dicha imagen. Puedes leer ¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta? y realizar el recorrido

Comment: Gracias @ʀᴏᴅʀɪɢᴏʀᴀᴍɪʀᴇᴢ.

Comment: Al parecer esta tratando de leer la longitud de una de sus variables no definida, asegurese de haber inicializado previamente antes de su uso o si se asignaron los datos dentro del scope.

Comment: Comparto el script completo, la verdad no halló cual es la variable que no estoy declarando, el problema no es con la petición, porque si me llega la data.